# Dashcode - how to register and use my own filterPredicate procedurally

Tags: iphone, dashcode

In my Dashcode mobile app I have a listView that is bound to a datasource. By default it shows everything in the datasource. If I add a search field the user may limit the list to just the records that match their search text.

I want to create my own preset searches attached to buttons that would be able to load a list view and show only the records from my datasource that match my custom search.

It seems like this ought to be possible, but so far I haven't figured out how to register my own filterPredicate and then use it.

I'm guessing this is what I want to do because it seems like this is what the search field part does.

Has anyone figured out how to do this?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

According to the dashcode starter section, you could use something along the lines of:

```
itemDescription = Class.create(DC.ValueTransformer, {
    transformedValue: function(value){
            return "Page: " + value;        
    }
});
```